# Azure ARM template for an insights alert

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to create an azure template for an alert for a function.

When I deploy it I get the following unhelpful error:

```
BadRequest: {
  "code": "InternalServerError",
  "message": "Exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.MonitoringServiceException' was thrown."
}
```

I can create the alert manually, and I've copied the template syntax so I'm not really sure whats wrong. This is my template:

```
 {
      "comments": "Detect failing job",
      "type": "microsoft.insights/alertrules",
      "name": "scheduledeletejobfailing",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "location": "North Europe",
      "scale": null,
      "properties": {
        "name": "scheduledeletejobfailing",
        "description": "The scheduled job to delete cached files is failing",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "condition": {
          "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.ThresholdRuleCondition",
          "dataSource": {
            "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleMetricDataSource",
            "resourceUri": "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', parameters('appname'))]",
            "metricNamespace": null,
            "metricName": "D1-ScheduledDeleteJobChecker Failures"
          },
          "operator": "GreaterThanOrEqual",
          "threshold": 1,
          "windowSize": "PT5M"
        },
        "action": {
          "odata.type": "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Insights.Models.RuleEmailAction",
          "sendToServiceOwners": false,
          "customEmails": [
            "address@addy.com"
          ]
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('microsoft.insights/components', parameters('appname'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites',variables('functionHostingPlanName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01",
      "name": "[parameters('appName')]",
      "type": "microsoft.insights/components",
      "location": "North Europe",
      "tags": {
        "[concat('hidden-link:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('appName'))]": "Resource"
      },
      "properties": {
        "ApplicationId": "[parameters('appName')]",
        "Request_Source": "IbizaWebAppExtensionCreate"
      }
    }
```

Note I haven't included the actual function website because it's just getting too long, but I can if it would help

Comment: Hi @ross, it would help if you can produce the full template for reproduction

Comment: I don't think it matters, as this looks like a bad input to this particular call @ju

Comment: Why it doesn't help to have the full template @4c, it helps issue reproduction much faster.

Comment: @ross, how did you create the template in this example? Did you look at the schema and construct it by hand, or did you use the Automation script feature in the Azure Portal?

Comment: Hi. I wrote everything but the alert using samples from the quickstart git repo. The alert one was created using the Azure portal.

Comment: How do you create the alert rule using the Azure portal? It is for Azure function correct?

Comment: Yup, created in the portal and it works fine.

Comment: The exact problem cannot be solved with given information. Similar ARM-template can be found from https://www.olivercoding.com/2018-07-07-azure-deployment/.